# PHP laravel Adldap- Migration from 4.2 to 9

Tags: php, migration, laravel-9, laravel-4.2, adldap

I am migrating laravel 4.2 to laravel 9 and in laravel 4.2 we have used adLDAP package and in laravel 9 we are using Adldap2. In laravel 4.2 we had manually create the connections and use folder()->listing() method for getting users attributes. How to Use it in Laravel 9 as I have installed Adldap2.

Instead of the folder()->listing() I tried with Adldap->search()->in(basedn)->select()->get();
I got 10000 arrays with Adldap\Model\groups or User or OU. But I couldn't iterate through thatas the values showed null

Comment: I used search()->users()->get(); in adldap2 to fetch users but it is not bringing all the users from AD around 50000-60000 users are there. Can any one help.
And can we use any condition for fetching search()->users()->where for fetching users whose account expire within a week etc